# What is openstack ceilometer alarm creation error "Missing argument: \"data\""

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, openstack, ceilometer

I facing this error :

```
*{"error_message": {"debuginfo": null, "faultcode": "Client", "faultstring":    "Missing argument: \"data\""}}*
```

I am doing the rest call in php for alarm creation as

```
$json = '\'{"alarm_actions": ["log:///tmp/tst.txt"], "description":  " Test of CPU usage high", "threshold_rule": {"meter_name": "cpu_usage_high", "evaluation_periods": 2, "period": 10, "statistic": "avg", "threshold": 40.0,"query":[{"field": "resource_id", "type": "", "value": "500a1594-4972-7968-2914-c333201585bd", "op": "eq"}], "comparison_operator": "gt" }, "repeat_actions": "FALSE", "type": "threshold", "name": "cpu_high_alarm_ada_9007"}\'';

$result = json_decode ($json);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$result);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


$result     = curl_exec($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

To check validity of json use [online json validator.](http://jsonlint.com/)

Here, in json data i was sending *"False" (With quotes).* But server was expecting data *false(without quotes).*